# Añadir atributos extra en un compentente en un libreria propia en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

¿Cómo se añaden atributos personalizados en un componente propio que está dentro de un modulo propio (librería de android)?

```
app:miatributo="lo que sea"
```

y posteriormente con java leer el valor del atributo.

Me estoy mirando esta respuesta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs) a ver si lo consigo!

Comment: no entiendo muy bien lo que deseas y veo la respuesta que agregas, lo que deseas es que la aplicación pueda leer los datos de la library?

Comment: He creado una libreria par aun control personalizdo y me gustaría agregarle atributos propios app:miatributo

Comment: Más o menos lo e conseguido, con attrs.xml y en java TypedArray(), mañana publicare como lo he hecho, para si se puede optimizar o es mejor hacerlo de otra forma etc...

Comment: Entiendo ahora lo que deseas!, esas propiedades son determinadas por el namespace, me refiero a xmlns.

Comment: De hecho veo la respuesta que agregaste, el primer comentario hace referencia al documento https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) existe un ejemplo de esto, como ejemplo una vista personalizada, defines las propiedades:

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

y en la vista accedes a las propiedades, definiendo el namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews">
 <com.example.customviews.charting.PieChart
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Como realizar la lectura de las propiedades a traves de [TypedArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html)

```
public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.PieChart,
        0, 0);

   try {
       mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PieChart_showText, false);
       mTextPos = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PieChart_labelPosition, 0);
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
}
```